# Redirect Restricted Page to 404

Tags: redirect, 404-error

Is there a way to show a 404 page if the current logged in user does not have the right clearance to view the page? I am looking for a PHP method, something like

```
if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) { show_404(); exit(); }
```

I have thought about using a redirect, but I would like to keep the url the same.

Comment: If you are denying access to a user for a page which exists, 404 is the wrong error code to use. A 401 or 403 would make more sense.

Comment: You are right. I was under the impression from the client that he did not want anyone without access to even know the page existed, throwing a 401 would say it exists but prohibited. Nonetheless, it would be an easy change to throw a 401 instead.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I was able to display a 404 error by using the following code in my header.

```
<?php
  global $wp_query;
  $wp_query->set_404();
  status_header( 404 );
  get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
?>
```

To break it down:
`$wp_query->set_404()`: tells the wp_query this is a 404, this changes the title
`status_header()`: sends a HTTP 404 header
`get_template_part()`: displays the 404 template

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would also use `http_status_code(404);` prior to setting the template to insure that the header is correct (which is significantly faster than the wordpress `status_header( 404 );` function). If you are concerned with page rank, you should also put a `Disallow` rule in your robots.txt to indicate that it is not a public resource.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create a page that show error message and then redirect user to that page? Here is a simple way to achieve that:

Open the `404.php` file and add these lines to the top of it:

```
/**
 * Template Name: 404 Page
 */
```

Create a page with `404 Page` template. Then redirect users:

```
if ( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    $404_page = get_permalink( $404_page_id );
    wp_redirect( $404_page );
    exit();
}
```

The reason you should use a page for 404 request is: in WP 404 page actually is a page that **doesn't exists**, WP has to search for *all of its content* before returning the 404 page and that work is a waste of resource. Using a pre-configured page that might help you run your blog faster.

Comment: I have thought about using this. But a couple downfalls that I see is that two 404 templates would have to be created and maintained (page and real). The client would have to create a 404 page. And I would like to keep the URL the same. Example, if I go to http://www.example.com/restricted, I would not be redirected to .../404/

Comment: Actually I just realized that the 404.php is the template. My mistake.

Comment: No, that is a pretty terrible idea if you like having any kind of page ranking. Search engines only consider pages that return a 404 or any 4xx range header as viewer error, and will happily index anything that returns a 200 page. If you do a redirect, then you are telling crawlers that your not found page is a valid page, and it will mess up your page ranking badly. All you really need to do when you get a 404 page is do `http_response_code(404); exit();`. If you want a page, then use `get_template_part( 404 );` before exit. That is also much faster than any wordpress functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement where I should not let users access the author.php page based on the role a user was in. I register the template_redirect action to do my checks and redirect to 404 page even before the actual page is loaded.

Registration:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', [ $this, 'handle_inactive_users']);
```

Handler:

```
public function handle_inactive_users() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->is_author() ) {
        $user = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        if ( is_a( $user, \WP_User::class ) && $user->has_cap( 'inactive' ) ) {
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
            get_template_part( 404 );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

If you chose to only use the following code snippet in the middle of template part, the page may have already been rendered partially and you are not actually redirected to a 404 page. So better to do it in the `template_redirect` action -

```
$wp_query->set_404();
status_header( 404 );
get_template_part( 404 );
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code to file **404.php** in actually used theme directory *(wp-content/themes/..../404.php)*:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

This code must start from begin of file *(without any characters before)*.

Link to original: [How to Redirect your 404 page to the Home Page in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-redirect-your-404-page-to-the-home-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: The OP is actually looking for a way to have 404 displayed for users that don't meet a certain criteria, e.g. "If user A doesn't have the 'can_edit' capability, then display a 404 page."

Comment: Do not redirect 404s. `Location: xxx` sets a 301 header, which tells crawlers that there is actually a valid resource, and kills your ranking when they determine that there isn't.