# How to properly print a 404 error without redirecton? (i.e. keeping the current URL)

Tags: urls, buddypress, 404-error, private, content-restriction

There are some pages on my BuddyPress install that I would like to hide by printing a 404 error.

With the help of the following question: [Redirect Restricted Page to 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24891/redirect-restricted-page-to-404)
I came up with this code:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set_404();
status_header( 404 );
get_template_part( 404 );
exit();
```

Most of the page is hidden nicely and a 404 error is printed, however what has been printed before this code remains (including the header title of the page I want hidden).

Unfortunately I can't move this code higher up, before anything gets printed.

So is there a way to **clear everything that has been printed before** and then **print a fresh 404 error** but with **keeping the current URL**? (So no redirection to the 404.php page.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a filter outside of your template for this:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpa62226_template_include', 1, 1 );
function wpa62226_template_include( $template ){
    if( is_page( 'some-page' ) ) :
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        $template = locate_template( '404.php' );
    endif;
    return $template;
}
```

Your code is executed before the template is loaded, so it becomes a non-issue.

Comment: I tried to add this filter to the functions.php and to the bp-custom.php files but neither seem to work. Are you sure this is supposed to work on BuddyPress?

Comment: It seems that the code is never run at all. I tried the following code to test for that:
`add_filter( 'template_include', 'hide_page_template_include', 1, 1 );
function hide_page_template_include( $template ) {
    return locate_template( '404.php' );
}` Nothing happens at all, so it seems that this does not work on BuddyPress. (The expected behavior was for it to print a 404 error page for any page that is called.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with BuddyPress, but it's possibly an issue of priority. You can inspect the global `$wp_filter` to see if BP is adding its own filter, or try altering priority.

Comment: Tried it in the `functions.php` page instead of `bp-custom.php` with the `wp` filter and it works like a charm! Thanks! :)